# Django: How to create a dynamic related_name for an inherited parent model?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have 4 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class A(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="u_a", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(A):
    user= models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="u_b", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    #isn't the code repeated???
    b_field = CharField(max_length=255)

class C(A):
    user= models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="u_c", on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    #isn't the code repeated???
    c_field = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Here, A has a `ForeignKey` relationsip with **User** and a reverse relationship as `u_a`. But **B** and **C** are children of **A**.

So It appears to me as if Do not repeat your code is violated. How to overcome this?

Comment: If you're manually typing out a class for each letter of the alphabet and creating a database relvar for each one, then you're probably doing something wrong, but if you insist on doing this and want to save typing, why not just use `eval` to generate the necessary classes in the module's \_\_init\_\_?

Answer (score 2):

To work around this problem, In your model `class A(models.Model)` The part of the value should contain `'%(app_label)s'` **and/or** `'%(class)s'`. see the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name)

`'%(class)s'` is replaced by the lower-cased name of the child class that the field is used in.

`'%(app_label)s'` is replaced by the lower-cased name of the app the child class is contained within. Each installed application name must be unique and the model class names within each app must also be unique, therefore the resulting name will end up being different.

```
class A(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="%(class)s_set", 
          on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #user= models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_set", 
          #on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(A):
    b_field = CharField(max_length=255)

class C(A):
    c_field = CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: The docs are using this for defining relations on abstract models. Will this also work for multi table inheritance?